# INNER JOIN two BigQuery tables based on common timestamps within a range of each other?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two table in BigQuery. Basically one has a bunch of data that is based around a Timestamp. The second set of data has another feature to add to the first set, also with a Timestamp. However, the timestamps aren't necessarily the same. However, I do know that they will be within 30 seconds of each other.

I was thinking I could do JOIN... ON abs(Timestamp1 - Timestamp2) < 30, but that's not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do CROSS JOIN. It is not very efficient, but would work if the tables are relatively small. Syntax (also using Standard SQL, see Mikhail's link how to enable it):

```
select
  ts1, x, ts1, y
from MainTable
cross join SecondTable
where abs(ts1 - ts2) < 30
```

For very large tables, you might have to do something more elaborate, like bucket both sides by minute, and do an equality JOIN. You'll need to also support case when JOIN crosses to the neighbor bucket, something like:

```
SELECT
  ts1, x, ts2, y
FROM MainTable 
JOIN 
(SELECT *, round(ts2/30) as bucket FROM SecondTable 
   UNION ALL
 SELECT *, round(ts2/30-1) as bucket FROM SecondTable 
   UNION ALL
 SELECT *, round(ts2/30+1) as bucket FROM SecondTable)
ON round(ts1/30) = bucket
WHERE abs(ts1-ts2) < 30
```

If there is more than one match and you need to select the best one, do something like

```
select * 
from (
   select *, MIN(ABS(ts1-ts2)) over(partition by ts1) as min_diff
   from ( <previous query> ))
where abs(ts1-ts2) = min_diff;
```

Comment: Ended up just rounding the Timestamp to the nearest minute because that's good enough for my purposes, but thank you!

Comment: hi @Michael. thank  you for pointing limitation (it worked with inline data but not with tables) in my answer (i deleted it to not to confuse other users).